# Fluent nHibernate error CreatingSessionFactory with Oracle

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

When I attempt to BuildSessionFactory() I get an error saying it cannot find the following assembles:

Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver, NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000

I have a reference to the Oracle.DataAccess version 4.11 in my bin folder and local, I am using:

Oracle 10 and 
Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4

And calling with the method below:

```
public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        FluentConfiguration idk = Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(OracleDataClientConfiguration
                .Oracle9
                .UseReflectionOptimizer()
                .MaxFetchDepth(3)
                .AdoNetBatchSize(500)
                .ConnectionString(cs => cs
                .Server("Paul-PC")
                .Port(1521)
                .Instance("xe")
                .Username("xxxx")
                .Password("xxxx")
                .Pooling(true)
                .StatementCacheSize(100)
                .OtherOptions(
                "Min Pool Size=10;Incr Pool Size=5;Decr Pool Size=2;")
            )
            // It does this automatically.. but I like to be explicit ;)
            .ProxyFactoryFactory("NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle")
            .ShowSql()
            )
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(PortalUserMap)));

        idk.ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema);

        return idk.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

The PortalUserMap class is below:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using Mobisoft.Portal.Security.Entities;

namespace Mobisoft.Portal.Security.Mappings
{
    public class PortalUserMap : ClassMap
    {
        public PortalUserMap()
        {
            Table("PORTALUSER");

```
        Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name, "NAME");
    }

}
```

Please someone help me, I have been trying to find an answer online for two days now.

Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the reference to Oracle.DataAccess.dll in your project, setting CopyLocal to True.

Answer (score 1):

Fluent NHibernate 1.1 reference NHibernate 2.1.X , you need to reference fluent NHibernate 1.2 in your project before you can use it with NHibernate 3.0.4 or higher which i guess that what you are using.
you can download it from here 
http://fluentnhibernate.org/dls/v1.x/fluentnhibernate-NH3.0-binary-1.2.0.694.zip